cannot login to Assembly Configurator
I cloned my app from github:
autodesk-platform-services/aps-assembly-configurator:
I published to https://config1-25b8553ff2b6.herokuapp.com/ but I cannot login…
I have not specified the SERVER_SESSION_SECRET..what will be that value? My Autodesk login password or I have to specify something in BIM 360 OR ACC to link the files to my app?
Does this configurator only works if I login with my Autodesk account?
Thank you,
Ruben Murray
I want to load the viewer and be able to drag the components to the main drawing

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
